# how to make unique field exception message on django

Tags: python, django

I have a create document form which has only two fields first, title second, a foreign key to Note model.

Now i want to make the document title unique so i used;

`title = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='document-title', unique=True)`

Well it works! but it doesnt show any feedback that new Document couldnt created...
here is the documentation i tried to follow: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#considerations-regarding-model-s-error-messages

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Document

class DocumentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = {'title',}
        labels = {'title': '',}

        widgets = {'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'document_title'}),}

        error_messages = {
            NON_FIELD_ERRORS: {
                "unique_together": "model name is not unique.",
            }
        }
```

## views.py

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            document = form.save()
            dummy_note = Note.objects.create(document=document)

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/note')


    form = DocumentForm
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'note/home.html', {'form': form, 'documents': documents})
```

## home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container d-flex flex-column">
  <center class="p-3">
    Note App Home Page!
  </center>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    
    <div class="card m-5" style="width: 20em;">
      <div class="card-header">
        Create Document
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form method=POST>
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{form.as_p}}

          <button name="create_document" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </form>        
      </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="card m-5" style="width: 20em;">
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <!-- <li class="list-group-item">An item</li> -->

        {% for document in documents %}
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <a href="{% url 'document-page' document.title %}">{{document.title}}</a>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}

      </ul>
    </div>
  
  </div>

  


</div>




{% endblock %}
```

i tought it would display a message right next to the input field but it doesnt show anything...
I want to have a display under/next to the input field how can i do it?

Comment: Can you share the view and template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create a new form in case the POST request is invalid, so constructing a new form should be done in the `else` clause in case of a GET request (method is *not* `POST`):

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            dummy_note = Note.objects.create(document=form.save())
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/note')

    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    return render(
        request, 'note/home.html', {'form': form, 'documents': documents}
    )
```

As for the error message, this is not a `unique_together`: the uniqness is defined on the `title` field, so you can override the error message with:

```
class DocumentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = {
            'title',
        }
        labels = {
            'title': '',
        }

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'document_title'}),
        }

        error_messages = {
            'title': {
                'unique': 'model name is not unique.',
            }
        }
```

---

> **Note**: While most forms do not process media files, it is probably better to pass [**`request.FILES`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) to the form anyway, such that if you later add an extra media field, all views that use the form will indeed handle the files properly.

Comment: thank you for great explanation!!
and also i write down your note ;)